# JQuery: Getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I am working on a data table and getting this error in the Chrome console **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollHeight' of undefined**

I have not worked with scrollHeight, but the error is related to scrollHeight.   My Javascript is minified, so I have no clue which line is throwing the error.

```
var table = $('#dataMatrixCustomTab').DataTable({
                    scrollY: "80vh",
                    scrollX: "100%",
                    bScrollCollapse: true,
                    bPaginate: false,
                    ordering: false,
                    fixedColumns: true,
                    destroy: true,
                    bAutoWidth: true,
                    autoWidth: true,
                    searching: false,
                    info: false,
                    iLeftWidth: 150,
                    scroller: true,
                    autoWidth: false,
                    bDeferRender: true,
                    responsive: true,
                    fixedColumns: {
                        leftColumns: 2
                    },
                    drawCallback: function (settings, start, end, max, total, pre) {
                        if ($('#dataMatrixCustomTab_wrapper .dataTables_scrollBody').hasScrollBar()) {
                            $('#dataMatrixCustomTab_wrapper .show-graph-bar').addClass("custom-graph-icon");
                        }
                        else {
                            $('#dataMatrixCustomTab_wrapper .show-graph-bar').removeClass("custom-graph-icon");
                        }
                    },
                    initComplete: function () {
                        $('.broker-toggle', '#dataMatrixCustomTab_wrapper').on('click', function (e) {
                            $("#fullviewBroker").empty();
                            $('.data-loading-wrapper').show();
                            $('.broker-modal').toggleClass('is-visible');
                        });
                        $('.stat-toggle', '#dataMatrixCustomTab_wrapper').on('click', function (e) {
                            $("#full_viewStatistics").empty();
                            $('.data-loading-wrapper').show();
                            $('.statistics-modal').toggleClass('is-visible');
                        });

                    }
                });
```

Comment: Looks like you can't use vh units, only px or a number for scrollY: https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollY

Comment: @NathanielFlick please mention the line which causes the problem.

Comment: The first line in your DataTable function: scrollY: "80vh"

Comment: @NathanielFlick thanks for pointing out the area. i will change and let you know. thanks